# After Insert trigger creation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I would like to insert one new row with my trigger into my new table after something inserted a row into my original table, but I wish to add a name to this id based on row details/column values.

I am using case/then/when command:

```
USE [DB1]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[Trigger1]    Script Date: 19/07/2017 15:16:31 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Trigger1]
ON [SourceTable]
AFTER INSERT 
AS  

insert into [dbo].[DestinationTable] ([ID],[NAME]) (select id, name = CASE
                  WHEN XXXX THEN '*****'
                  WHEN XXXX THEN '*****'
                  WHEN XXXX THEN '*****'
                  WHEN XXXX THEN '*****'
                  WHEN XXXX THEN '*****'
                  WHEN XXXX THEN '*****'
                  END
FROM SourceTable WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE ID=@@identity)
```

It is failing....

Comment: Do you mean select top 1 row order by date put in a CTE and run case select on cte? Perhaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like marc_s said in comment, all you need is to select from `Inserted` table. It contains all new rows inserted in SourceTable.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Trigger1]
ON [SourceTable]
AFTER INSERT 
AS 
BEGIN

  insert into [dbo].[DestinationTable] ([ID],[NAME]) 
  select id, name = CASE
                  WHEN XXXX THEN '*****'
                  WHEN XXXX THEN '*****'
                  WHEN XXXX THEN '*****'
                  WHEN XXXX THEN '*****'
                  WHEN XXXX THEN '*****'
                  WHEN XXXX THEN '*****'
                  END
  FROM inserted

END
```

Comment: IS Inserted the name of the temp table which created by system automatically after a new row was inserted the source table?

Comment: Yes it exists only inside the trigger.

Answer (score 2):

You need to select from the `Inserted` pseudo table which includes all rows (it can and will be multiple rows, too!) that were inserted with the operation that fired this trigger:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Trigger1]
ON [SourceTable]
AFTER INSERT 
AS  
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[DestinationTable] ([ID], [NAME]) 
        SELECT
            i.ID,
            CASE
               WHEN XXXX THEN '*****'
               WHEN XXXX THEN '*****'
               WHEN XXXX THEN '*****'
            END
        FROM  
            Inserted i
```